# Which TrustFrameworkExtension policy file to use with Groups Demo sample?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am looking to run the Groups policy sample from https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/groups

The TrustedFrameworkExtensions_Group.xml file references a policy called B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions. However there are several TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml files in the containing git repo. Which one needs to be uploaded for the base policy for the Groups Demo to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bit of a lottery to figure this out.

I always use the MFA one as that seems to cover most bases.

Or sometimes the local and social.

But you need to use the whole set from that starter pack.

Comment: Thanks!! I stumbled on the Starter Pack also and got it working using the Social and Local base custom policy files. Appreciate your help! :)